# What are some methods to do early prediction of a classification problem?

Tags: time-series, classification

I recently built a classifier for a company regarding detection of equipment failure.  Currently, my model takes all the current features of the system, and predicts if the equipment is going to need maintenance or not.  Data is collected per minute.  It is a binary classification problem.  I used logistic regression and was able to get over 99.8% accuracy, precision and recall.

The company was happy with this, but now wants me to tell them this at least 5 - 15 minutes in advance.  This new problem is basically an early detection problem, where I have to predict the future of the equipment using current information.

I am wondering if anyone can help me with some problem setup to solve this problem.  I am also looking for a way to include time series into this prediction.

Things I've tried:

- Shifting all the labels back 15 minutes.  This failed terribly because once an event occurs, the next 20,000 - 30,000 data points will still say the equipment failed.  If I shift the data forward by 15 points, there will only be 15 data points that were different from my previous data point for each event.
- Breaking the data down into "event packages", where I locate the events, and then take the previous 15 minutes data up to the event as a positive training example.  Then I take some other random points as negative training examples.  I then feed all 15 minutes data into my model.  But then I realized that I was still feeding current time information into my model, so this did not give that 5 mins ahead prediction.

What I am thinking of trying next:

- Take data 15 - 5 minutes before an event and label those as positive examples.  This way, my model may be able to predict 5 minutes in advance

I am wondering if this community can give me some suggestions for this "early prediction" problem.  I am mainly looking for:

- How should I manupliate my data to make the classifier most effective
- How should I incorporate temporal correlation into my model, and how to format my data to achieve it
- Some other models/success stories from you guys on a similar problem to this.

Comment: So you are trying to predict an event that will happen 15 time points in advance (since you are collecting data by the minute)? How many data points do you have before that?

Comment: Yes, even 5 minutes is good enough.  I have a data set of 785 features and 525600 examples.  However, there are only ~50 positive samples and the rest are negative.  Also, the positive examples could be caused by failure or because a worker shutting down the equipment just to check something.  Once a positive example occurs, it may stay positive for about 20,000 to 30,000 points because it may take weeks to fix.

Comment: This will be tough, you may be better off doing something like anomaly detection. Do you have additional variables that you could use in the analysis? Whether is was failure or checking? Anything else?

Comment: Unfortunately, we do not.  Anomaly detection is kind of like what I built at the very beginning.  I built some univariate anomaly detection such as IQR, Mod Z-score.  And some multivariate anomaly detection such as PCA and looking at T-statistic of each time steps sample.  However, the company was looking for some "early prediction" predictive power.